# Java Web Scanner

Tags: java, image-scanner

I have a working java web app for document management. On document creation i have a file attachment option that works perfectly.

But now i'm supposed to implement the following functionality:

When user creates document from web browser 
he can press the button called "Scan" that will scan the document in his scanner (HP scanner or Cannon) create a pdf out of scanned pages and attach this pdf to document.

So it's an auto scan magic functionality.

Now is this even possibly? I know that some requirements are insane but i can't do anything about it, my employee is desperate to have this functionality in his web document management.

I'm frustrated and clueless of how can i implement this in java web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to develop a Java Applet to put in your web page, using a Java Twain Implementation such as [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/).

Comment: Do you know any scanning java applet for ISIS?

Comment: @MarekBar Check this component out: http://www.atalasoft.com/products/wingscan/ I have worked with their .net components for scanning and they are very robust.